# With graphs in SQLAlchemy, how can one find nodes that are not connected to some specific other node by an edge?

Tags: python, graph, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have saved a directed graph in a table similar to the example in the SQLAlchemy documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/examples.html#directed-graphs

Now I save a specific node `a`. With SQLAlchemy ORM I want to build a query that finds all nodes which do *not* have an edge going to `a`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_non_touching(ref_node):
    qry = session.query(Node)
    qry = qry.filter(~Node.lower_edges.any(Edge.higher_id == ref_node.node_id))
    qry = qry.filter(~Node.higher_edges.any(Edge.lower_id == ref_node.node_id))
    qry = qry.filter(Node.node_id != ref_node.node_id) # exclude node "a" itself as well
    return qry.all()

a = session.query(Node).get(1)
res = get_non_touching(a)
```